# Move files by reading their file names to different directories

Tags: shell, files, rename

I need to move files by reading their names.
I have to move system generated files and the names include a time stamp. I need to move the files by reading the file name by month.

If the file name contains `201601*.txt`, then move to `2016/January` directory. If the file name contains `201602*.txt` then move to `2016/February` directory etc.

Comment: That doesn't look good in the 2016-directory. Wouldn't you rather use subdirectories 01..12 instead? And should the name be shortened by that?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the date strings are in the file names and all the files are in the same directory, you could do:

```
mv 201601*.txt 2016/January
```

Doing this 12 times manually would be a pain, so I would create a list with the number and corresponding month name:

```
$ paste <(printf '%s\n' {01..12}) <(cal 2016 | grep -Po '\s+\K[A-Z]\w{2,}') 
01  January
02  February
03  March
04  April
05  May
06  June
07  July
08  August
09  September
10  October
11  November
12  December
```

And then parse it to build the `mv` commands:

```
$ paste <(printf '%s\n' {01..12}) <(cal 2016 | grep -Po '\s+\K[A-Z]\w{2,}') | 
    while read num month; do echo mv "*2016$num*" 2016/"$month"; done
mv *201601* 2016/January
mv *201602* 2016/February
mv *201603* 2016/March
mv *201604* 2016/April
mv *201605* 2016/May
mv *201606* 2016/June
mv *201607* 2016/July
mv *201608* 2016/August
mv *201609* 2016/September
mv *201610* 2016/October
mv *201611* 2016/November
mv *201612* 2016/December
```

Once you're sure that does what you need, remove the `echo` to actually move the files:

```
paste <(printf '%s\n' {01..12}) <(cal 2016 | grep -Po '\s+\K[A-Z]\w{2,}') | 
    while read num month; do echo mv "*2016$num*" 2016/"$month"; done
```

#### Explanation

The `grep -Po '\s+\K[A-Z]\w{2,}')` will run `grep` with Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (`-P`) and will print only the matching portion(s) of each line (`-o`). The regular expression used will look for one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`) followed by a capital letter (`[A-Z]`) and 2 or more word characters (`\w{2,}`). The `\K` means "ignore everything before this" which will cause the command to only print the part of the matching strings *after* the whitespace. The whole thing simply prints the list of months.

Comment: HI,Pls explain the work of   " '\s+\K[A-Z]\w{2,}" part

Comment: @user1924765 is that clearer?

Comment: Also, @user1924765, if this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

[Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) has a nice function to rename files based on name patterns: [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). In the replacement pattern, `$f` designates the whole original name and `$1`, `$2` etc. are the parenthesized groups. Use an array to store month names.

```
autoload -U zmv
months=(January February March April May June July August September October November December)
zmv '(2016)(<1-12>)*.txt' '$1/$months[$2]/$f'
```

Because the pattern here is simple, it isn't very painful to adapt this to bash and ksh, with a loop. You need to take care of a few things: strip the leading 0 from the month number so that it isn't interpreted as octal; array indices start at 0.

```
months=(January February March April May June July August September October November December)
for f in 2016[0-9][0-9]*; do
  y=${f:0:4} m=${f:4:2}
  mv -- "$f" "$y/${months[${m#0}]}/$f"
done
```

Another approach is the Perl rename script (either the [Debian version](https://gist.github.com/3939556) or the [Unicode::Tussle version](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Unicode::Tussle)).

```
rename 'BEGIN {@months = qw(January February March April May June July August September October November December)}
        s!^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})!$1/$months[$2]/&!' 2016[0-9][0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `bash` solution that runs through the files, moving those that match the `yyyymm` component (for values of `yyyy` in the range 2000-2099):

```
months=('' January February March April May June July August September October November December)

for f in 20[0-9][0-9][0-3][0-9]*
do
    year=$(echo "$f" | grep -Po '^20\d\d')           # Extract the four digit year, 20nn
    mm=$(echo "$f" | grep -Po '^(?<=20\d\d)\d\d')    # Find the two digit month number 01-12
    month=${months[$mm]}                             # Convert to a month name

    test -n "$year" -a -n "$month" && echo mv "$f" "$yyyy/$month/$f"
done
```

Remove the `echo` prefix from the `mv` when you are ready to run.

---

If you know that all the files begin with `2016` you can simplify the processing somewhat:

```
for f in 2016[0-3][0-9]*
do
    mm=$(echo "$f" | grep -Po '^(?<=2016)\d\d')    # Find the two digit month number 01-12
    month=${months[$mm]}                           # Convert to a month name

    test -n "$month" && echo mv "$f" "2016/$month/$f"
done
```